# Ubuntu cannot find extra HDDs with fdisk -l

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, uefi

I installed the Ubuntu 18.04 server edition on the server with UEFI boot. And then I switch the boot model from dual to efi.
There are one SSD and three HDDs on the server. I tried to use fdisk -l to find HDDs but I only can see the SSD drive. It shows that the disk type of the SSD is GPT.
How can I find the extra three HDDs? Because the server has been sent to the server room, it's a little difficult for me to config the BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by hardware RAID card. If a server has raid card, you should config it at bios and then you can find it on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the boot mode (UEFI or Legacy) would cause you to not see the additional hard drives. It is just used to load the OS, which then sees and mounts the drives.

Do you know if the drives are mounted properly?

A couple things to try:

```
dmesg | grep ata
```

See if it mentions any errors about the drive.

Install updates and reboot.

```
apt update && apt upgrade && reboot
```